# Может ли ответ быть принят более одного раза?

Tags: поддержка

В подробной расшифровке репутации (<kbd>Профиль</kbd> - <kbd>Активность</kbd> - <kbd>Репутация</kbd>) присутствует довольно странное сообщение в подсказке к принятому ответу:

> ответ был принят 1 раз

[image: принят 1 раз]

Возникает резонный вопрос: а может ли ответ быть принят более 1 раза? Или в чем здесь сокровенный смысл этого одного раза? (на enSO тоже присутствует: `answer was accepted 1 time`).

Comment: Принял, отменил, снова принял. Какое число будет?

Comment: @Qwertiy надо проверить